# How to restrict user from using Rear-Facing Camera in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an iOS app, in which at one point the user takes a picture. However, I want the user to ONLY be able to use the front facing camera. That is, they should not have access to the rear camera. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func takePicture(sender: UIButton) {

    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Front) != nil {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .Camera
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
        imagePickerController.cameraDevice = .Front
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(
            title: "No Camera",
            message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style:.Default,
            handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alertVC,
                              animated: true,
                              completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Although this defaults the camera to be front facing, it still offers users the choice to switch to the rear camera. Is there a way I can restrict this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow the user the freedom offered by a UIImagePickerController, simply don't use UIImagePickerController. Devise your own picture-taking interface (by way of AVFoundation), where *you* are in total control.